# redirect rewritten url using haproxy

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

Using haproxy version 1.4.24 on Ubuntu 14.04

I would like to use haproxy to rewrite and redirect urls which are no longer valid to their new equivalent. I am already using haproxy as the reverse proxy and load balancer. I have the rewrite working correctly but when I try to redirect I either end up with no redirect or in a redirect loop. I read on a few places that a technique for this is to rewrite and redirect the url using prefix in the frontend but I'm not having any luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    spread-checks 0

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    timeout queue 20000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout server 50000

frontend haproxy-0-80
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    default_backend haproxy_service
    acl old_url path_beg -i /post
    # The below doesn't appear to have any effect
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /post/\d+/(.+)/?     \1\ /\2
    redirect prefix http://10.0.3.10 code 301 if old_url

backend haproxy_service
    balance leastconn
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    # The below properly handles the rewrite
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /post/\d+/(.+)/?     \1\ /\2
    server ghost-0-2368 10.0.3.220:2368 maxconn 100 cookie S0 check
```

Comment: I could upgrade to the 1.15.x version if this isn't possible in 1.14.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out I was very close to a working config.

Changing the redirect line to read `redirect prefix / code 301 if old_url` made it work as expected.

I wrote a blog post which outlines the problem in a little more detail: https://fromanegg.com/post/2014/12/05/how-to-rewrite-and-redirect-with-haproxy/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me as the acl condition is being checked after the request has been regex replaced, meaning the old_url condition will fails if the check is executed after reqrep.